# Javascript regex test weirdness

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain this (using node version 4.2.4 repl)?

```
var n; //undefined
/^[a-z0-9]+$/.test(n);  // true!
/^[a-f0-9]+$/.test(n);  // false
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? What do you think or expect does the regex try to match on?

Comment: n is converted to a string since `test()` expects a string, so its now `"undefined"`. `"undefined"` passes the first test but not the second

Comment: One regex has a-z and other has a-f, second case will fail as u does not come in a-f range

Comment: OK everyone, thanks. I'd say it violates the principle of 'least surprise' that rather than an empty string, undefined gets converted to the *word* "undefined"!

Comment: btw you did not mention the weirdness of this code, please explain your doubt properly so that people can answer your question without guessing your doubt

Comment: Musa, Iván and slebetman all understood my question perfectly (probably by actually reading my example), and all gave me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable passed to `.test()` is first converted to string. This is specified in the spec:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.3

which points to:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2

which says:

> 1. Let R be this RegExp object.
> 2. Let S be the value of ToString(string).

So basically you're testing:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/.test("undefined");  // true!
/^[a-f0-9]+$/.test("undefined");  // false
```

It should now be obvious why the second test returns `false`. The letters `u`, `n` and `i` are not included in the test pattern.

---

Note: The function `ToString()` in the spec refers to the type coercion function in the underlying implementation (most probably C or C++ though there exist other implementations of js in other languages like Java and Go). It does not refer to the global function `toString()` in js. As such, that second line in the spec basically means that `undefined` will be treated as `"" + undefined` which returns `"undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's converting `undefined` to a string. So:

```
var pattern1 = /^[a-z0-9]+$/  
var pattern2 = /^[a-f0-9]+$/  
pattern1.test("undefined") // There are only letters  
pattern2.test("undefined") // defed match, but unin does not.
```

Answer (score 0):

`RegExp.test` treats `n` as a string `"undefined"`.
So, the range `[a-f]` does not cover all the characters of `undefined` string.
In your case, the "mimimum allowable" range for passing regexp check would be `[a-u]`

```
var n; //undefined
console.log(/^[a-u]+$/.test(n));   // true
```